# How to make some products shippable only to one city at checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I need some products like x, y, z shippable to only one city(A) at the checkout page. Based on the selected shipping address how can I disable shipping those products(x, y, z) to all other cities except the specific city(A)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible with de default magento settings.
But there's a module that can achieve this; Amasty Shipping Restrictions